# How to JSON encode arrays in array from iOS to PHP

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I try to JSON encode NSDictionary into NSArray upload to PHP web-services.

This is how I JSON encode my NSArray:

```
NSError * error;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:my_array_1 options:0 error:&error];
NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```

Then I insert this JSON String into another array by:

```
NSString * jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"{\"request\":\"syncBookmark\",\"bookmark_array\":\"%@\",\"user_id\":\"%@\"}", jsonString, user_id, nil];
NSData * requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];
```

Before I request the webservices, the JSON encoded string is like:

```
{"request":"syncBookmark","bookmark_array":"[{\"PostId\":\"4\",\"last_edit_date\":\"2014-03-03 01:05:37\",\"BookmarkId\":\"1\",\"last_sync_date\":\"\",\"is_active\":\"1\"}]","user_id":"7"}
```

I can echo the 'user_id' in PHP which is '7' correctly, but when I check the array - is_array($bookmark_array) in PHP it just return FALSE. Am I doing the way wrongly to put arrays in array?

Comment: Please post your php code

Comment: All that extra manipulation is only needed if you intend to have "embedded/nested JSON", where the data is actually JSON-encoded twice.  This would be unusual, so you're very likely shouldn't be doing it.  And, as Rob suggests, it can be done more effectively and reliably by simply running the data through JSON encoding twice.  Normally you just put an array in a dictionary (or in another array) by just putting the array in the dictionary and JSON-encoding the whole thing -- the JSON encoder knows how to handle nested arrays/dictionaries.

Comment: (JSON is incredibly simple and easy to use, once you understand it.  If you haven't done so, go to json.org and spend the 5-10 minutes it takes to learn the syntax.  Then understand that a JSON "object" maps perfectly to an iOS "NSDictionary", and a JSON "array" maps perfectly to an iOS NSArray.  So converting back and forth between the two forms is trivial so long as you have a good JSON encoder/decoder -- no other manipulation is needed 99% of the time.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother doing the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` stuff. Let `NSJSONSerialization` do all of the necessary quoting for you.

So, if you really need that `jsonString` as a string that your PHP will recursively un-encode, just JSON encode the array, and then put that in another dictionary and then encode that again:

```
NSError  *error;
NSData   *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:my_array_1 options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"request"        : @"syncBookmark",
                             @"bookmark_array" : jsonString,
                             @"user_id"        : user_id};

NSData   *finalData      = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
```

That should create a payload much like you said you wanted in your question.

Having said that, a more logical approach would be:

```
NSError  *error;

NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"request"        : @"syncBookmark",
                             @"bookmark_array" : my_array_1,
                             @"user_id"        : user_id};

NSData       *finalData  = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
```

If that's what generated your payload, then your PHP wouldn't have to do multiple calls to `json_decode`.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you enter JSON string as string and it is obviously escaped by the `stringWithFormat` method.

You should create a `NSDictionary` and serialize that together. So instead of serializing `my_array_1` variable, you will serialize the dictionary.

Create the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = @{ @"request" : @"syncBookmark", @"bookmark_array" : my_array_1 };
```

Then serialize the dictionary:

```
NSError * error;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:&error];
NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is the correct way to serialize a JSON object, not inserting serialized objects into another string. Although I see why you wanted to do that.